# Extracting numeric data lines between lines or two markers

Tags: python

I am trying to extract several lines of the data from a text file. this data set sits between two markers ("et 1027" and  "t  0")  as follows:

```
.... (some data)

et  1027

  0.00000E+00  1.00000E-05  3.00000E-03  6.00000E-03  9.00000E-03  1.20000E-02

  1.50000E-02  1.80000E-02  2.10000E-02  2.40000E-02  2.70000E-02  3.00000E-02

  ...
  ...

t  0

.... some more data
```

I attempted to use  the following script but really did not work because it ended up printing all the numbers outside of the markers  as well. I just want to print the data line set between these two  markers (not include the markers). here is my failed script. Does anyone how any idea how to set the beginning and end tags and print the lines between?  Thank you in advance.

```
import re

file = open ('data.txt', 'r')

for line in file:

   line= line.strip()

   y= re.findall('[0-9]+', line) 

   print y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like this

```
import re

file = open ('data.txt', 'r')

allowed = False

for line in file:
    line= line.strip()
    if line == 'et 1027':
        allowed = True
    if line ==  't 0':
        allowed = False
        break
    if allowed:
        y= re.findall('[0-9]+', line) 
        print y
```

Comment: Suggest adding `continue` after `allowed = True`, otherwise 1027 will be included in the output.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in a simple way: read the file until you meet the first marker, then print everything you read until you meet the next marker

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:

   line= data.readline()

   while line != 'et 1027':
        line= data.readline()
   else:
        line= data.readline()
        while line != 't 0':
            print y
            line= data.readline()
```